# CSS3 Transition Keeps Resetting Rotation

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS3 Transition but right at the end of the transition my rotation resets to normal state. The HTML and CSS are simple:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#"><span></span>Test</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25px;
}
a span:before {
    content:'>';
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
a:hover span:before {
    margin-left: 55%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

The transition goes as expected except at the very end of the animation the rotation resets to normal state instead of persists. I've created a [JSFiddle as an example](http://jsfiddle.net/y5w4ddb6/). How do I keep my rotation to persist?

Comment: Please clarify the issue properly...

Comment: rotation is only here when state is hover. nothing wrong with your code i believe. If you want to keep the rotation/margin set when hover state is lost, you may want to use animation and forwards :)

Comment: @C-linkNepal I'm uhh, not sure how to clarify this any more - the css rotation does reset at the end of the transition and I provided a live example along with my code...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding  `display: inline-block`
like this:

```
a:hover span:before {
    margin-left: 55%; 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); 
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5w4ddb6/1/).

Explanation.

The pseudo elements, like `:before` or `:after` are inline, by default, so they have issues with being transformed, thus you need to set them to `display: block` or `display: inline-block`.

Comment: Please, include some explanation, so other people with this issue will benefit from this solution.

Comment: @LcSalazar I added the explanation.

Comment: I'm still not seeing the difference by using inline-block....

Comment: @C-linkNepal, what browser are you using? In Chrome(at least on my version) without the `inline-block` the `>` finishes the animation, thus rotates, and then teleports back to it's initial state( `>` ), aka not rotated. With `inline-block`, upon finishing the animation it stays still and looks something like a Cyrillic l, or in my demo it stays like a `v` because I removed the `-` from `-90deg`.

Comment: I'm using latest version of firefox...

Comment: Ah, yes. Well he added only the `-webkit-` prefix on his fiddle so it works only in webkit based browsers.

Answer (score 1):

## Its Working Use this Method

- Don't use `margin` for animation use `translate` istead.
- for better smooth transitions

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y5w4ddb6/3/)

---

**html**

```
<a href="#"><span>></span>Test</a>
```

**css**

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25px;
}
a span{
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
a:hover span{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(50%);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(50%);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(50%);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(50%);
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(50%);
}
```

Comment: on the demo you have 4 times `-webkit-transform`